# How to use gzip compression in Python XMLRPC server

Tags: python, server, compression, gzip, xml-rpc

How can I adapt the sample code for an XML RPC server and client from the [Python 2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html) so that it uses gzip in the transport between the client and server?  The following is the sample code:

**Server**

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

# Restrict to a particular path.
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

# Create server
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000),
                            requestHandler=RequestHandler)
server.register_introspection_functions()

# Register pow() function; this will use the value of
# pow.__name__ as the name, which is just 'pow'.
server.register_function(pow)

# Register a function under a different name
def adder_function(x,y):
    return x + y
server.register_function(adder_function, 'add')

# Register an instance; all the methods of the instance are
# published as XML-RPC methods (in this case, just 'div').
class MyFuncs:
    def div(self, x, y):
        return x // y

server.register_instance(MyFuncs())

# Run the server's main loop
server.serve_forever()
```

**Client**

```
import xmlrpclib

s = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8000')
print s.pow(2,3)  # Returns 2**3 = 8
print s.add(2,3)  # Returns 5
print s.div(5,2)  # Returns 5//2 = 2

# Print list of available methods
print s.system.listMethods()
```

But this is all carried over non-compressed plaintext.  I've been reading through the documentation on the xmlrpc library and it looks like it has built-in options for gzip compression, but I haven't been able to figure out how to actually use it.